# C switch case REALY weird result

Tags: c, random, switch-statement

So ive tried to use the rand() command in C, in this case to generate random number between 1 to 6. that part went perfectly, but then i tried to use the switch method to count how many times each number apeared, and the results were... weird.

heres the code:

## include

```
int main() {

    int num;
    int number;
    int one;
    int two;
    int three;
    int four;
    int five;
    int six;

    printf("enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    for(int n = 1; n < num + 1; n++){
        number = (rand() % 6) +1;
        printf("%d", number);
        switch(number){
            case 1:
                one++;
                break;
            case 2:
                two++;
                break;
            case 3:
                three++;
                break;
            case 4:
                four++;
                break;
            case 5:
                five++;
                break;
            case 6:
                six++;
                break;
        }
    }
    printf("number of ones: %d\n"
            "number of twos: %d\n"
            "number of threes: %d\n"
            "number of fours: %d\n"
            "number of fives: %d\n"
            "number of sixes: %d\n",
            one, two, three, four, five, six);
    return 0;
}
```

when i ran it and wrote in 10, 10 random numbers realy apeared, but these are the results:

number of ones: 1978168284

number of twos: -2

number of threes: 1307605979

number of fours: 1978192464

number of fives: 6422480

number of sixes: 6422299

I looked at the code a few times and I just have no idea how that happend... if anyone has an edvice of fixisg that, please tell me (:

Comment: Initialize your variables.

Comment: ... meaning set `one = two = ... = six = 0;` before the loop.  C doesn't do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

Variables with automatic storage duration are not initialised to zero.

You need to do that yourself.

The behaviour of reading an uninitialised variable is undefined in C: you must initialise them.